# How to serialize data-structures when each member is a different derived class?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, data-structures, json.net

I'm using `C`# and `Newtonsoft.Json`. I am making an `RPG` where the characters are saved to disk using `Json`. `Characters` include an `inventory`.

My '`Inventory`' Class:

```
public class Inventory
{
    public Dictionary<EquipmentSlot, Equipment> Equiped = new Dictionary<EquipmentSlot, Equipment>();
    public Dictionary<CurrencyType, float> Currency = new Dictionary<CurrencyType, float>();
    public Item[] Loot = new Item[LootLimit];

    //some extra methods and stuff
}
```

"`Equipment`" is an `abstract class` from which "`Armour`", "`Weapon`" and "`Shield`" are derived. "`Armour`" is not a `non-abstract class`, "`Weapon`" is an `abstract class`, and `Shield` is `non-abstract` for the moment because I haven't designed it yet.

The problem is that because the reference to the character's equipment is cast as "`Dictionary<EquipmentSlot, Equipment>`", `Json` only saves the properties of the "`Equipment`" base `class`. Then when it de-serializes, it attempts to instantiate "`Equipment`" and crashes because "`Equipment`" is `abstract`.

I can see that this is going to be a massive problem for me because everywhere I have `Dictionaries`, `Lists`, `Arrays` and other data-structures typed as base class, where each member is a derived `class`.

- How to make this work?
- Is there a better form of serialisation than Json?
- Or is there a better version to use than Newtonsoft.Json.Dll?
- Do I need to write custom serialisation into my classes? (example?)
- Is there some better solution?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Most JSON serializers in .Net have mechanisms for handling polymorphic types.  Json.NET has [`TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm).  `DataContractJsonSerializer` has [type hints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as does [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  What serializer are you using?

Comment: I am using Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080387/json-net-does-not-serialize-properties-from-derived-class will be of some use. Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513042/json-net-serialize-deserialize-derived-types. Or perhaps https://christianarg.wordpress.com/2012/11/06/serializing-and-deserializing-inherited-types-with-json-anything-you-want/. A few minutes with your favorite search engine looking for *serialize derived class json.net* should lead you to the answer.

Comment: See also [Deserializing polymorphic json classes without type information using json.net](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19307752/10263)