# Json.net How do I serialize or deserialize all property , even include non [DataMember]?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I'm using Json.net(Newtonsoft.Json) to serialize or deserialize some class.

There is my class

```
[DataContract]
Public class Person
{
   [DataMember]
   public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
   public string StudentName { get; set;}
}
```

Now I want to serialize student, But Looks like **Json.net only serialize or deserialize `DataContract` class and `DataMember` property**. It always **ignore my `StudentName` property**, But I need it include in.

Is there any way to fixed this? thank you.

Comment: Have you tried newtonsoft.json?

Comment: @willaien What? I'm currently using Newtonsoft.Json, and I thought It's the Json.net .....

Comment: Alright. Here's what's likely happening. By default, newtonsoft.json will serialize all properties, but due to your class inheriting attributes from its parent, you have told newtonsoft.json to not serialize those properties without attributes. If you remove all of the attributes, it should work.

Comment: This looks like what you need:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055225/configure-json-net-to-ignore-datacontract-datamember-attributes

Comment: @Todd , That's a really good way, It will be more better If you write it as a answer. Also It that will be a low performance problem?

Comment: @willaien do you know when such rules came into Newtonsoft.Json serializer? We updated in from 3.5 to latest 13 and now we have absolutely the same trouble such as in this topic. Now I'm wondering is it possible to change with some setting, because I'm not sure we need all the fields in JSON to include Todd's decision

Answer (score 0):

According to [official site](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) you just have to add `[DataMember]` attribute to `StudentName` to have this property in the json string.

Comment: Is there any other way? Because I don't want add it in my all classes. there is so many classes.....

Answer (score 0):

If you need to include the `StudentName` property just add `[DataMember]` attribute to this property.

However, another easier way can be to completely remove `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` as Newtonsfot.Json doesn't really need them to determine which properties to include.

```
public class Person
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
}

public class Student : Person
{
   public string StudentName { get; set;}
}

// ...

Student student = new Student() { ID = "1", StudentName = "John" };
string resultJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(student);
```

Comment: Is there any alternate way? Because the classes so many...both `[DataContract]` and `non [DataContract]`

Comment: @qakmak Todd already showed the solution. *ContractResolver*.