# Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, expression-trees

In .NET world, when it comes to object serialization, it usually goes into inspecting the object's fields and properties at runtime. Using reflection for this job is usually slow and is undesirable when dealing with large sets of objects. The other way is using IL emit or building expression trees that provide significant performance gain over reflection. And the latter is most modern libraries pick when dealing with serialization. However building and emitting IL at runtime takes time, and the investment is only paid back if this information is cached and reused for objects of the same type.

When using Json.NET, it is not clear to me which method described above is used, and if the latter is indeed used, whether the caching is used.

For example, when I do:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Foo { value = 1 });
```

Does Json.NET build the Foo's member access info and cache to reuse it later?

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer for you, but the source for [Json.NET](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) is on github and It does say that "Json.NET is a popular high-performance JSON framework for .NET".  If you do a quick search for cache on the source you will find that there is indeed quite a bit of caching going on.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Yes, it does.**  Json.NET caches type serialization information inside its [`IContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) classes [`DefaultContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs) and [`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs).  Unless you specify a custom contract resolver, this information is cached and reused.

For `DefaultContractResolver` a global static instance is maintained internally that Json.NET uses whenever the application does not specify its own contract resolver.  `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, on the other hand, maintains static tables that are shared across all instances.  (I believe the inconsistency arises from legacy issues; see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30740734/json-net-html-helper-method-not-regenerating/30743234#30743234) for details.)

Both of these types are designed to be fully thread-safe so sharing between threads should not be a problem.

If you choose to implement and instantiate your own contract resolver, then type information will only be cached and reused if you cache and reuse the contract resolver instance itself.  Thus, Newtonsoft [recommends](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm):

> For performance you should create a contract resolver once and reuse instances when possible. Resolving contracts is slow and implementations of IContractResolver typically cache contracts.

**If memory consumption is a problem** and for whatever reason you need to minimize the memory permanently taken by cached contracts, you can construct your own local instance of `DefaultContractResolver` (or some custom subclass), serialize using that, and then immediately remove all references to it, e.g.:

```
public class JsonExtensions
{
    public static string SerializeObjectNoCache<T>(T obj, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        settings = settings ?? new JsonSerializerSettings();
        bool reset = (settings.ContractResolver == null);
        if (reset)
            // To reduce memory footprint, do not cache contract information in the global contract resolver.
            settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, settings);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (reset)
                settings.ContractResolver = null;
        }
    }
}
```

And if you are using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver`, switch to `DefaultContractResolver` with an appropriate [naming strategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategySkipSpecifiedNames.htm) such as:

```
settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy() };
```

The majority of cached contract memory (**[but not all](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/2414)**) will eventually get garbage collected.  Of course, by doing this, *serialization performance may suffer substantially*.  (Some tables containing reflected information about e.g. `enum` types and data contract attributes are shared globally and not reclaimed.)

**For further information** see Newtonsoft's [Performance Tips: Reuse Contract Resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/performance.htm#ReuseContractResolver).

Comment: We see across UTs that the contracts saved in our `MyContractResolver : CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` type are cached statically, even across multiple `MyContractResolver` types. This si causing suprising falures when some UTs run together as they don't set up the contracts as needed. Is the pointer to reuse the same `ContractResolver` instance still valid?

Comment: @ElFik - `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` behaves differently from `DefaultContractResolver` -- it caches contract information globally whether you want it or not.  If you don't want that, switch to `DefaultContractResolver` with an appropriate naming strategy.

Comment: @dbc and ElFik you save my day! This is a horrible fail of CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver implementation. Thank you so much!