# Too many objects was created in Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, memory, json.net

I have next code for deserialize/serialize objects:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization;

namespace api
{
    static class JSONHelper
    {
        //Generate JSON only with ID and revision
        private class ContractResolverSaveIdAndRevision : DefaultContractResolver
        {
            private readonly List<string> allowedPropNames;
            private readonly string startingSymbol;

            public ContractResolverSaveIdAndRevision()
            {
                allowedPropNames = new List<string>();
                allowedPropNames.Add( Constants._id );
                allowedPropNames.Add( Constants.__rev );

                startingSymbol = "_";
            }

            protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties( Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization )
            {
                IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties( type, memberSerialization );

                return collectAllowedProperties( properties, allowedPropNames, startingSymbol );
            }
        }

        //Generate JSON only with ID
        private class ContractResolverSaveId : DefaultContractResolver
        {
            private readonly List<string> allowedPropNames;
            private readonly string startingSymbol;

            public ContractResolverSaveId()
            {
                allowedPropNames = new List<string>();
                allowedPropNames.Add( Constants._id );

                startingSymbol = "_";
            }

            protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties( Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization )
            {
                IList<JsonProperty> properties = base.CreateProperties( type, memberSerialization );

                return collectAllowedProperties( properties, allowedPropNames, startingSymbol );
            }
        }

        private static readonly JsonSerializer jsonSerializerWithoutSettings = new JsonSerializer();

        private static readonly ContractResolverSaveIdAndRevision saveIdAndRevisionContractResolver = new ContractResolverSaveIdAndRevision();
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings settingsWithIdAndRevision = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = saveIdAndRevisionContractResolver };
        private static readonly JsonSerializer jsonSerializerWithIdAndRevision = JsonSerializer.Create( settingsWithIdAndRevision );

        private static readonly ContractResolverSaveId saveIdContractResolver = new ContractResolverSaveId();
        private static readonly JsonSerializerSettings settingsWithId = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = saveIdContractResolver };
        private static readonly JsonSerializer jsonSerializerWithId = JsonSerializer.Create( settingsWithId );

        public static object DeserializeJson( Type type, string json )
        {
            lock ( jsonSerializerWithoutSettings )
            {
                object obj = null;

                try
                {
                    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader( json );
                    JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader( stringReader );

                    obj = jsonSerializerWithoutSettings.Deserialize( jsonTextReader, type );

                    jsonTextReader.Close();
                    stringReader.Dispose();

                    jsonTextReader = null;
                    stringReader = null;
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Debug.DebugPrinter.PrintError( e );
                }

                return obj;
            }
        }

        public static T DeserializeJson<T>( string json )
        {
            lock ( jsonSerializerWithoutSettings )
            {
                T obj = default( T );

                try
                {
                    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader( json );
                    JsonTextReader jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader( stringReader );

                    obj = jsonSerializerWithoutSettings.Deserialize<T>( jsonTextReader );

                    jsonTextReader.Close();
                    stringReader.Dispose();

                    jsonTextReader = null;
                    stringReader = null;
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Debug.DebugPrinter.PrintError( e );
                }

                return obj;
            }
        }

        public static string SerializeJson( object value )
        {
            lock ( jsonSerializerWithIdAndRevision )
            {
                string json = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                    JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter( stringWriter );

                    jsonSerializerWithIdAndRevision.Serialize( jsonTextWriter, value );

                    json = stringWriter.ToString();

                    jsonTextWriter.Close();
                    stringWriter.Dispose();

                    jsonTextWriter = null;
                    stringWriter = null;
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Debug.DebugPrinter.PrintError( e );
                }

                return json;
            }
        }

        public static string SerializeJsonWithoutRevision( object value )
        {
            lock ( jsonSerializerWithId )
            {
                string json = string.Empty;

                try
                {
                    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                    JsonTextWriter jsonTextWriter = new JsonTextWriter( stringWriter );

                    jsonSerializerWithId.Serialize( jsonTextWriter, value );

                    json = stringWriter.ToString();

                    jsonTextWriter.Close();
                    stringWriter.Dispose();

                    jsonTextWriter = null;
                    stringWriter = null;
                }
                catch ( Exception e )
                {
                    Debug.DebugPrinter.PrintError( e );
                }

                return json;
            }
        }

        private static IList<JsonProperty> collectAllowedProperties( IList<JsonProperty> objectProperties, IList<string> allowedPropNames, string startingSymbol )
        {
            return objectProperties.Where( p => allowedPropNames.Contains( p.PropertyName ) || !p.PropertyName.StartsWith( startingSymbol ) ).ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

I started Visual Studio profile and collection information about memory. And I found many object from Newtonsoft.Json.dll. And I don't how to fix it or clear memory.

Do you know how i can improve this behavior?

Thanks

Screenshot from profiler:
[image: Application Memory]

Comment: To improve performance, Json.NET caches reflection information in the contract resolver.  See [Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information).  So you could eliminate your static resolvers and serializers and allocate each time you serialize.  Of course, performance will suffer.  But why is this a problem?  How much memory is Json.NET actually consuming?  (I can't read Russian so I can't tell from the bitmap.)

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty - 82540 bytes. Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ExpressionValueProvider - 91692 bytes. Thanks for your recomendation. I'll try without static resolver and serializer.