# Sophisticated Json response not correctly map in c# classes

Tags: c#, .net, json

I have this JSON response and I create an equivalent C# class.
But when I try to convert this JSON to c# result not completed.

**JSON Response**

```
{
    "result": "success",
    "totalresults": 1,
    "startnumber": 0,
    "numreturned": 1,
    "orders": {
        "order": [
            {
                "id": 26,
                "ordernum": 9658502986,
                "userid": 18,
                "frauddata": "",
                "lineitems": {
                    "lineitem": [
                        {
                            "type": "domain",
                            "relid": 9,
                            "dnsmanagement": 0,
                            "emailforwarding": 0,
                            "idprotection": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**C# Class**

```
public class RootObject
    {
        int totalresults { get; set; }
        int startnumber { get; set; }
        int numreturned { get; set; }
        orders orders { get; set; }
    }
    public class lineitem
    {
        public string type { get; set; }
        public int idprotection { get; set; }
    }

    public class lineitems
    {
        public List<lineitem> lineitem { get; set; }
    }

    public class order
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public long ordernum { get; set; }
        public int userid { get; set; }
        public string fraudmodule { get; set; }
        public string fraudoutput { get; set; }
        public string frauddata { get; set; }
        public lineitems lineitems { get; set; }
    }

    public class orders
    {
        public List<order> order { get; set; }
    }
```

I used ***JsonConvert.DeserializeObject*** but in result orders property always empty!

[image]

I need to orders property. Can anybody help me?

Comment: Is that really the model being returned? With a object property called "orders" and an array called "order" nested in that property? I assume it is, but that is a very confusing model.

Comment: Also, in your example, you're working with a RestSharp.RestResponse<T> not a raw JSON string. RestSharp automatically deserializes your JSON for you when you use one of those generic methods.

Comment: The properties of `RootObject` are private.  You need to make them public, as explained in [Why are some members missing when trying to print an object by serializing to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48156976/3744182).  (The answer to that question has some workarounds if you cannot make the members public.)  In fact I think this is a duplicate; agree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try like this;

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString)
```

Comment: Won't help, because class definition does not match json object

Comment: Class definition is match with json object! i reduce properties in class and json in this post!

Comment: @SaharSarikhani I tired with your class definition. Everything is ok with this Json and Class definition. I can see orders on debug.

Comment: Yes, but i used interface for rootobject and with interface orders is empty always. Any way i use class now ,thank you.but when lineitem in return object is empty jsonconvert has error.