# c# private, serializable data model for Newtonsoft JSON

Tags: c#, json.net, inner-classes

I would like to achieve something actually quite simple, but I keep running into walls. I have a class that should give access to a REST-API. Such an `ApiClient` should be created on basis of a certain class of my program via constructor. So far, so simple.

Now my first idea was to embed the corresponding data models for the JSON serialization as a `private class` inside this outer class. But then it came to my mind that Newtonsoft JSON cannot see `private` members. So I thought I would make the classes `public` and somehow hide the constructors of these data classes to the outside so that they are only visible from the class ApiClient. But in C# the access modifier `friend`, known from VB.net, is missing. But I don't want to set all data classes `public` either, because they are basically irrelevant for the rest of the program.

Is there a way to implement this somehow so that it doesn't get too complicated? I have already seen approaches with a private class and a public interface. But I don't think that's very nice either. I also saw an approach using data annotation to make the properties visible to Newtonsoft JSON anyways, but that didn't look too attractive to me either.

To say it in short: I want to transfer data to a REST-API and encapsulate the whole thing in a class. I want to use a class for the data that has to be transferred. But if possible this class should only be visible for the ApiClient class and the serializer.

Is there a best-practice solution for this rather common task?

```cs
public class ApiClient {
    private ApiClientData _serializableData;

    // This class should only be visible to the ApiClient class and the serializer
    private class ApiClientData {
        public string Data1 {get; private set;}
        public int Data2 {get; private set;}

        public ApiClientData(SomeOtherDataModel input) {
            Data1 = input.SomeVal;
            Data2 = input.OtherVal;
        }
    }

    public ApiClient(SomeOtherDataModel baseData) {
        _serializableData = new ApiClientData(baseData);
    }

    public void CallService() {
        // Newtonsoft JSON
        string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_serializableData);

        CallBlackBoxFunctionToCommunicateWithTheRestServer(jsonString);
    }
}

public void main() {
    SomeOtherDataModel data = GetDataFromSql();
    ApiClient client = new ApiClient(data);
    client.CallService();
}
```

Comment: `friend` in VB is called `internal` in C#

Comment: @Gimly But with friend, you can do more. There is no way in c# to control, for example, that a method can only be called from within the same namespace.

Comment: So typically what you do with APIs published as a library is have an `IClient`, a concrete `ApiClient` and all models are public POCOs. You send POCOs in and get POCOs out. All the weird private etc. logic does not live in those models.

Comment: @Gimly that is exactly what `internal` does - internals can only be called from the same Assembly, unless you add a `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute

Comment: @zaitsman So there is no way to prevent the construction of my data objects from outside my ApiClient class?

Comment: Ahm, those would be `internal`

Comment: @zaitsman `internal` relates to the assembly, not the namespace or even the class. Because my whole project only consists of a single assembly, using `internal` would be useless.

Comment: If your project consists of a single assembly, AND you want to encapsulate this logic as much, you're doing it wrong :)

Comment: To be fair, your question is far from clear, and your code sample doesn't really help. Could you try to describe more precisely what you're trying to achieve and where you are blocked?

Comment: @Gimly I find it difficult to describe it more precisely. I just want to transfer data to a REST-API and encapsulate the whole thing in a class. I want to use a class for the data that has to be transferred. But if possible this class should only be visible for the `ApiClient` class and the serializer.

Comment: *it came to my mind that Newtonsoft JSON cannot see `private` members* - it can if you mark them with `[JsonProperty]` or with data contract attributes.  See [Why are some members missing when trying to print an object by serializing to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48157367/3744182) for a list of options for serializing nonpublic members.  And Json.NET is perfectly happy to serialize and deserialize private **types**.