# JsonSerializerSettings to change case of property name but not name of property's property

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

I am using below settings for camel casing of my class property.

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };
```

Some of the property in the object are of some other class type. I do not want to change case of those properties.

Eg:

```
Public Class CaseToChange
{
    public string StringProperty{get;set;} //Change to camelCase
    public SomeOtherType OtherTypeProperty{get;set;} //Change name of this to camelCase but not property name of "SomeOtherType"

}
```

How to achieve this with JsonSerializerSettings?

Comment: `JsonSerializerSettings` applies default settings to all types being serialized.  If you just want to change the casing of `CaseToChange` to camel case, you could apply [`[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) to it.

Comment: Do you **need** it to be in settings, or can you modify the type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you can modify your types to add [Json.NET serialization attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm), the easiest thing to do would be to add [`[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_NamingStrategyType.htm) to your `CaseToChange` type:

```
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class CaseToChange
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; } //Change to camelCase
    public SomeOtherType OtherTypeProperty { get; set; } //Change name of this to camelCase but not property name of "SomeOtherType"
}
```

(Or, if you are using a version of Json.NET earlier than 9.0.1, add `[JsonProperty("camelCaseName")]` to each property as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42093243/3744182).)

If you cannot modify the type and must camel-case the properties of `CaseToChange` only through serializer settings, you can create a [custom contract resolver](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) that returns camel-cased names for `CaseToChange` and unmodified names for other types.  The following does the trick:

```
public class OverrideContractResolver : ContractResolverDecorator
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, IContractResolver> overrides;

    public OverrideContractResolver(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Type, IContractResolver>> overrides, IContractResolver baseResolver)
        : base(baseResolver)
    {
        if (overrides == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.overrides = overrides.ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
    }

    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        IContractResolver resolver;
        if (overrides.TryGetValue(type, out resolver))
            return resolver.ResolveContract(type);
        return base.ResolveContract(type);
    }
}

public class ContractResolverDecorator : IContractResolver
{
    readonly IContractResolver baseResolver;

    public ContractResolverDecorator(IContractResolver baseResolver)
    {
        if (baseResolver == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.baseResolver = baseResolver;
    }

    #region IContractResolver Members

    public virtual JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        return baseResolver.ResolveContract(type);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then serialize with settings as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver =
        new OverrideContractResolver(
            new Dictionary<Type, IContractResolver> { { typeof(CaseToChange), new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver() } },
            new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver()),
};
```

And the resulting JSON will look like:

```
{
  "stringProperty": "string property",
  "otherTypeProperty": {
    "FooProperty": "foo",
    "BarProperty": 101
  }
}
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j3aSq2).

For optimal performance you may want to [cache instances of the contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182).

Answer (score 4):

Simply add the JsonProperty attribute as shown below and don't use the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` if you don't want camelCasing for the whole object tree.

```
public class CaseToChange
{
    [JsonProperty("stringProperty")]
    public string StringProperty { get; set; } //Change to camelCase

    [JsonProperty("otherTypeProperty")]
    public SomeOtherType OtherTypeProperty { get; set; } //Change name of this to camelCase but not property name of "SomeOtherType"
}
```