# How do I camel case a specific property using Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json.net, camelcasing

I want to camel case specific properties of an object using Json.NET rather than all of the properties.

I have an object like this:

```
class A {
    public object B { get; set; }
    public object C { get; set; } // this property should be camel cased
}
```

I want it to get serialized to this:

```
{ B: 1, c: 2 }
```

I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783137/default-camel-case-of-property-names-in-json-serialization) about camel casing *all* properties unconditionally, which is done using:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a, settings);
```

But I couldn't find a counter-part question for camel casing a specific property. How is this done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change property names when serializing with Json.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8796618/how-can-i-change-property-names-when-serializing-with-json-net)

Comment: @maccettura This isn't really a duplicate. He's asking the more general question about just changing property names to something else. I'm talking about camel casing them.

Comment: @pushkin Yet the second "strategy" is an exact duplicate of that question. I don't see how it's "less preferable" nor why you think that

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Though the second, less optimal, strategy may be a duplicate of the linked answer, my question is not a duplicate, nor is the more optimal strategy from my answer.

Comment: Then how about duplicate of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42092359/jsonserializersettings-to-change-case-of-property-name-but-not-name-of-property)?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yup, this is a dup, then. I missed that one in my searches. Thanks

Comment: I cannot blame you though, that was the 6th Google result, after duplicates of the one @maccettura linked

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Though now that I look more closely, he's technically asking about camelcasing an entire object, which is technically different. Or is that a strech?

Comment: I would consider " I do not want to change case of those properties." the same as "I want to camel case specific properties", but that's me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply [`JsonPropertyAttribute's NamingStrategyType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) to the field that you want to camel case:

```
class A 
{
    [JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
    public object C { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can specify the name of the Property directly:

```
class A 
{
    [JsonProperty("c")]
    public object C { get; set; }
}
```