# Disable JSON.Net PreserveReferencesHandling for single external type

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I'm having the issue where the $id and $ref properties in the generated JSON are not accepted by the external resource. But as we need this internally I can't just disable PreserveReferencesHandling globally.

How can I disable this just for a single type? I've seen the `[JsonObject]` attribute but as this class is from an external source I can't add the attribute to it...
I looked into the IContractResolver but couldn't figure out how to disable the reference handling there.

Thanks!

- JSON.Net v10.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a [custom `ContractResolver`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) that sets [`JsonContract.IsReference == false`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonContract_IsReference.htm) by overriding [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateContract.htm):

```
public class DisableReferencePreservationContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly HashSet<Type> types;

    public DisableReferencePreservationContractResolver(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        this.types = new HashSet<Type>(types);
    }

    bool ContainsType(Type type)
    {
        return types.Contains(type);
        //return types.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }

    bool? GetIsReferenceOverride(Type type)
    {
        return ContainsType(type) ? false : (bool?)null;
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        // Disable IsReference for this type of object
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        contract.IsReference = contract.IsReference ?? GetIsReferenceOverride(objectType);
        return contract;
    }
}
```

The constructor should be passed a list of types for which reference information is to be disabled.  Note that I am excluding this information for instances of the *exact type(s)* passed into the contract resolver.  If you want to exclude this information from instances of derived types as well, you could modify `ContainsType()` as follows:

```
    bool ContainsType(Type type)
    {
        return types.Any(t => t.IsAssignableFrom(type));
    }
```

Note also the contract resolver disables [`PreserveReferencesHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) when set in `JsonSerializerSettings`, but *not* when set directly with serialization attributes such as [`[JsonObject(IsReference = true)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm#IsReference) or [`[JsonProperty(IsReference = true)]`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_IsReference.htm) on the external types.

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c3Qnzn).

You might want to [cache the contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information) for best performance.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for!