# How to use PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects selectively?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

I have a structure of objects that I serialize to JSON, and there is one path that can have circular references. This problem can be solved using `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`, but unfortunately it creates another problem because it adds `$id` properties to all the objects. I don't want to clutter the serialized data, as it's supposed to be human readable and editable.
So, the question is there any way to make it add `$id` only to those objects that actually are included into reference loops?

Comment: In order to only serialize `$id` properties for objects that participate in reference loops, it would be necessary to make an initial pass through the serialization graph to identify all such objects -- but Json.NET is a single-pass serializer, so that isn't easily done.

Comment: You could restrict `#id` properties to specific types if that helps, see e.g. [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException “Self referencing loop detected” in library code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32275608/3744182) or [Disable JSON.Net PreserveReferencesHandling for single external type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44515823/3744182).

Comment: @dbc I can do loop detection before serialization, but in this case it would be necessary to somehow use this info in Json.NET to only append ids where necessary.