# How to extend JSON serialization (JsonConverter) with TypeNameHandling.Auto, WITHOUT adding $type manually?

Tags: json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

**I need to extend default serialization of any object** (that implements a specific interface) with, let's say for simplicity, additional properties in the generated JSON (and then be able to load this correctly).

**My problem** is that I've got **TypeNameHandling set to Auto** and if I create my custom JsonConverter (Newtonsoft.Json) and even invoke the original serialization (with the original supplied serializer by disabling my one for that time to avoid a loop) **I am not getting the "$type" property generated automatically** (which is required for proper deserialization). It's not automatically added by my parent and I cannot force the serializer to do it (reason below).

I am also not able to generate it myself, because **I don't have any access to my context, i.e. the Type of the property that contains the object instance that I'm serializing**, which states the *expected* type (to be compared with the actual one, to decide whether the $type should be generated or not). I can only generate it **always**. Is there any way to resolve this?

I want to avoid replacing the default serialization (only to extend it) and to keep the `Auto` `TypeNameHandling` behavior.

Comment: You have a couple of options: 1) You could have a `JsonConverter` that generates a default serialization then modifies it, as shown in [JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using `[JsonConvert()]`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509) or [Generic method of modifying JSON before being returned to client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35532466)...

Comment: ... or 2) You could add the properties with a custom contract resolver instead, as in [Json.net Add property to every class containing of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46549680) or [How to add metadata to describe which properties are dates in JSON.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46047308).  Does either approach work for you?  Should your question be a duplicate of any of those?

Comment: Thanks dbc. I was able to resolve my issue using different approach, by using a custom ContractResolver and skipping the JsonConverter altogether (similar to your 2nd suggestion set) - BUT - this still does not answer my original question. If I would be forced to use a custom JsonConverter (which gets the default serialization to modify it), I'm not able to auto-generate the "$type" property when (and only when) the instance is different than its property type, which is the behavior of `TypeNameHandling == Auto` (and I'm not able to get the property type inside the converter from anywhere).