# How to disable TypeNameHandling when specified in attributes by using JsonSerializerSettings in Json.NET?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Sometimes I need to suppress output of `"$type"` properties by Json.NET even when specified by [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm).  How can this be done?

My root class looks like below:

```
public class DomainResource
{
    [JsonProperty(ItemTypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto)]
    public List<Extension> Extensions { get; set; }
}
```

And in addition I have a class hierarchy for `Extension` such as the following:

```
public class Extension
{
    readonly string url;

    public string Url { get { return url; } }

    public Extension(string url)
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
}

public class IntegerExtension : Extension
{
    public IntegerExtension(string url) : base(url) { }

    [JsonProperty("ValueInteger")]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

I want to ignore `ItemTypeNameHandling` in certain scenarios during serialization, but I am not able to find a way to do that. 
I tried setting JsonSerializerSettings with TypeNameHandling.None as input for jsonconvert when I do not want `"$type"` properties using the code below:

```
public static string SerializeObject(object value)
{
    JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,

    };
    jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter
    {
        CamelCaseText = true
    });
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.None, jsonSettings);
}
```

And then use it as follows:

```
var res = new DomainResource();
res.Extensions = new List<Extension>();
res.Extensions.Add(new IntegerExtension("ewwer"){Value = 3});

var x = CustomJsonConvert.SerializeObject(res);
```

My desired JSON is:

> {"extensions":[{"valueInteger":3,"url":"ewwer"}]}

But instead it contains `"$type"` properties as shown below:

> {"extensions":[{"$type":"DicomtoJsonConverter.IntegerExtension,
>   DicomtoJsonConverter","valueInteger":3,"url":"ewwer"}]}

How can I suppress output of `"$type"` properties **without changing `DomainResource` class**?

Comment: It's not clear what exactly you are asking? Can you share some more details about what do you expect from the code and what actually is happening?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [custom `ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) to suppress output of type information even when specified by [`JsonPropertyAttribute.TypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_TypeNameHandling.htm), [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm) or [`JsonContainerAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonContainerAttribute_ItemTypeNameHandling.htm).  First, define the following contract resolver:

```
public class NoTypeNameHandlingContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        // Suppress JsonPropertyAttribute.TypeNameHandling
        property.TypeNameHandling = null;
        // Suppress JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling
        property.ItemTypeNameHandling = null;
        return property;
    }

    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);
        if (contract is JsonContainerContract)
        {
            // Suppress JsonContainerAttribute.ItemTypeNameHandling
            ((JsonContainerContract)contract).ItemTypeNameHandling = null;
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Then, modify `CustomJsonConvert.SerializeObject()` as follows:

```
public static class CustomJsonConvert
{
    // You may want to cache the contract resolver for best performance, see
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33557737/does-json-net-cache-types-serialization-information
    static readonly JsonSerializerSettings jsonSettings;
    static CustomJsonConvert()
    {
        jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new NoTypeNameHandlingContractResolver
            {
                NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
                {
                    // These are the settings used by CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver by default.
                    // Change them if this is not what you want.
                    OverrideSpecifiedNames = true,
                    ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
                },
            },
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.None,
            Converters = { new StringEnumConverter { CamelCaseText = true } },
        };
    }

    public static string SerializeObject(object value)
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, Formatting.None, jsonSettings);
    }
}
```

If you are using a version of Json.NET that predates [9.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/9.0.1) you will need to subclass `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` rather than subclassing `DefaultContractResolver` since [`NamingStrategy`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_NamingStrategy.htm) was introduced in that release.