# Convert object to JSON including values of method calls

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a complex object from a C# third-party library.

For explaining purposes my complex object could look something like this:

```
myobject.Property1
myobject.Property2
myobject.Property3.SubPropertyA
myobject.Property3.SomeMethodX()
```

Is it possible to configure Json.Net to include in the serialization of `myobject` also the name of the of the method and its return value?

I want to achieve a JSON like this:

```
{
 "Property1" : "valueOfProperty1" ,
 "Property2" : "valueOfProperty2" ,
 "Property3" : {
                  "SubPropertyA" : "valueOfSubPropertyA",
                  "SomeMethodX" : {JSON serialization of SomeMethodX's return value}
               }
}
```

I am thinking on using Reflection to call `SomeMethodX` by overriding `CreateProperty` method of the `DefaultContractResolver`

```
protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
{
    JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

    MethodInfo getServiceMethod = property.DeclaringType.GetMethod("MethodX");
    MethodInfo genericGetServiceMethod = getServiceMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { typeof(SomeMethodXReturnType) });//SomeMethodX is generic

    // To invoke the method I need a reference to the actual object, I don't know if it can be accessed through the available arguments????
    object returnValue = genericGetServiceMethod.Invoke(targetedObject, null);

    //next I guess I have to add the return value as an extra property for further serialization
    //I don't know how

    return property;
}
```

I mention again that I am trying to serialize an object from a library, and
not some custom object.

Because of my lack of experience with Json.Net I don't know if I am on the right track.

Comment: Make it your own Object - create a Helper class with a method that accepts the library object and spits out your Object. Serialize that.

The reason for this is so you can specify attributes on on the object and have quite a lot of type safety in your serialization.

Comment: Why do you care about the method name? You could just add a property and set its value as the return of the method. Wouldn't need to use  recursion for that.

Comment: @jpgrassi My object is provided by a library through a public interface. How can I set a property to that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a [custom `ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm) that subclasses [`DefaultContractResolver.CreateProperties`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateProperties.htm) and uses reflection to add synthetic a [`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Properties_T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty.htm) to the list of properties to serialize for each applicable method:

```
public class IncludeMethodsContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override IList<JsonProperty> CreateProperties(Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var properties = base.CreateProperties(type, memberSerialization);
        return properties.Concat(this.GetMethodProperties(type, memberSerialization)).ToList();
    }
}

internal static class ContractResolverExtensions
{
    static readonly HashSet<string> objectMethods;

    static ContractResolverExtensions()
    {
        objectMethods = new HashSet<string>(typeof(object).GetMethods().Where(m => IsCallableMethod(m)).Select(m => m.Name));
    }

    static Func<object, object> CreateMethodGetterGeneric<TObject, TValue>(MethodInfo method)
    {
        if (method == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var func = (Func<TObject, TValue>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<TObject, TValue>), method);
        return (o) => func((TObject)o);
    }

    static Func<object, object> CreateMethodGetter(MethodInfo method, Type type)
    {
        var myMethod = typeof(ContractResolverExtensions).GetMethod("CreateMethodGetterGeneric", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return (Func<object, object>)myMethod.MakeGenericMethod(new[] { type, method.ReturnType }).Invoke(null, new [] { method });
    }

    static bool IsCallableMethod(MethodInfo m)
    {
        return !m.ContainsGenericParameters && m.GetParameters().Length == 0 && !m.IsAbstract && m.ReturnType != typeof(void) && !m.IsSpecialName;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<JsonProperty> GetMethodProperties(this DefaultContractResolver resolver, Type type, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        if (type.IsValueType || memberSerialization == MemberSerialization.Fields || memberSerialization == MemberSerialization.OptIn)
            return Enumerable.Empty<JsonProperty>();
        var query = from m in type.GetMethods()
                    where IsCallableMethod(m)
                    where !objectMethods.Contains(m.Name) // Skip ToString(), GetHashCode() and GetType() and the like
                    let v = new MethodProvider(CreateMethodGetter(m, type))
                    select new JsonProperty
                    {
                        DeclaringType = type, 
                        PropertyType = m.ReturnType,
                        PropertyName = resolver.GetResolvedPropertyName(m.Name),
                        UnderlyingName = m.Name,
                        ValueProvider = v,
                        AttributeProvider = NoAttributeProvider.Instance,
                        Readable = true,
                        Writable = false,
                    };
        return query;
    }
}

class NoAttributeProvider : IAttributeProvider
{
    static NoAttributeProvider() { instance = new NoAttributeProvider(); }

    static readonly NoAttributeProvider instance;

    public static NoAttributeProvider Instance { get { return instance; } }

    public IList<Attribute> GetAttributes(Type attributeType, bool inherit) { return new Attribute[0]; }

    public IList<Attribute> GetAttributes(bool inherit) { return new Attribute[0]; }
}

class MethodProvider : IValueProvider
{
    readonly Func<object, object> methodGetter;

    public MethodProvider(Func<object, object> methodGetter)
    {
        if (methodGetter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.methodGetter = methodGetter;
    }

    #region IValueProvider Members

    public object GetValue(object target)
    {
        return methodGetter(target);
    }

    public void SetValue(object target, object value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, you would call it like:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new IncludeMethodsContractResolver(),
};
var customJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- You wrote, *I have to add the return value as an extra property for further serialization.  I don't know how*.  A contract resolver defines the rules for how to serialize a specific type to JSON.  As such it doesn't have access to any specific instance of the type, and so cannot access any return value directly.

  Instead, it must create an [`IValueProvider`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IValueProvider.htm) that gets and sets values when passed such an instance.  So, to serialize method values, I had to implement a custom value provider using a delegate manufactured from the `MethodInfo` of the method.
- Since the contract resolver makes heavy use of reflection, you may want to [cache it for best performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182).
- I suppressed serialization of the three parameterless methods of `object`, namely `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()` and `GetType()`.

Sample working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/l5dNsX).