# Serializing an Exception Return a Very Large JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, json.net

I'm migrating an application from full framework to net core.
I'm struggling to get the exception manager for the apis to get to work.

I'm currently using a attribute based solution.

I have this class

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override async void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        var ex = context.Exception;
        if (ex == null) return;

        context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(context.HttpContext.Response.Body))
        {
            var js = new JsonSerializer();
            js.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            js.Serialize(writer, ex);
            await writer.FlushAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

and I use the corresponding attribute on the desired controller.
    `[ApiExceptionFilter]`

The thing is, that when I catch the exception and throw it to the client as a JSON string. I got a 27mb download, and its because it's serializing the `TargetSite` and within of that it serialize the DefinedTypes which is a list of assemblies and types.

Does somebody know how can I serialize the exception avoiding those properties?

Here is an example of the exception:

```
{
Id: null,
Message: "Hubo errores en la validación de los parámetros de la operación.",
Data: { },
InnerException: {
Detail: {
Details: [
{
Key: "Cuit",
Message: "The field Cuit must match the regular expression '^[0-9]{11}$'.",
ParameterName: "request"
}
]
},
Action: null,
Code: {
IsPredefinedFault: true,
IsSenderFault: true,
IsReceiverFault: false,
Namespace: "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/",
Name: "Client",
SubCode: null
},
Message: "Hubo errores en la validación de los parámetros de la operación.",
Reason: {
Translations: [
{
XmlLang: "en-US",
Text: "Hubo errores en la validación de los parámetros de la operación."
}
]
},
Data: { },
InnerException: null,
TargetSite: {
Name: "HandleReply",
DeclaringType: "System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
ReflectedType: "System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
MemberType: 8,
MetadataToken: 100671507,
Module: {
MDStreamVersion: 131072,
FullyQualifiedName: "C:\Users\rotha\.nuget\packages\system.private.servicemodel\4.5.3\runtimes\win\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Private.ServiceModel.dll",
ModuleVersionId: "c5851175-5eba-412a-8f03-6cd647a2a897",
MetadataToken: 1,
ScopeName: "System.Private.ServiceModel.dll",
Name: "System.Private.ServiceModel.dll",
Assembly: {
CodeBase: "file:///C:/Users/xxx/.nuget/packages/system.private.servicemodel/4.5.3/runtimes/win/lib/netstandard2.0/System.Private.ServiceModel.dll",
FullName: "System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
EntryPoint: null,
DefinedTypes: [
"FxResources.System.Private.ServiceModel.SR, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.NotImplemented, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.__HResults, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.FxTrace, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.SR, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.Xml.XmlBinaryNodeType, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.Collections.Generic.KeyedByTypeCollection`1, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedCollection`1, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedKeyedCollection`2, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"System.Collections.Generic.SynchronizedReadOnlyCollection`1, System.Private.ServiceModel, Version=4.5.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
..........
```

this list of defined types, has like a million of items... :(

Comment: Its because you are writing the response body to the stream. Instead just pass the info about the exception.

Comment: sorry i'm not following you...

Comment: i need to send the exception as a json string, i guess i didn't explain that.

Comment: Why are you writing the exception to the response? Seems like that would leak details to the consuming application, which doesn't need to know *how* the API failed. Just that it failed. Seems like you should log the error and then write a  generic "Something went wrong" response for unhandled exceptions.

Comment: yes, you have a point there.

Comment: but, this i how is working now in full framework, but it doesnt serialize those properties DefinedTypes and TargetSite.

Comment: What are the values of [`((DefaultContractResolver)js.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableInterface`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableInterface.htm) and [`((DefaultContractResolver)js.ContractResolver).IgnoreSerializableAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreSerializableAttribute.htm)?

Comment: Also, what is the type of the exception you are serializing -- i.e. the return of `GetType()`?

Comment: The difference is likely related to [this change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881884), but I can't quite pin down where it's happening in the source, since `Exception` is marked as both `[Serializable]` and `ISerializable` in the [.Net core source code](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Exception.cs) (maybe that's the wrong location for the source?), and I don't have .Net core to debug.  Maybe the custom contract resolver from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881884 will resolve the problem?

Comment: i'm currently trying a System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException but it could be any exception.

Comment: Create a new object with the properties you want. `new { ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, ... }`.

Comment: well i have some faultexceptions from WCF services, on those cases that wouldn't work... :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write it using any writer, just use `context.Result`:

```
public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        var ex = context.Exception;
        if (ex == null) return;

        context.Result = new JsonResult(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, thanks for the example.
But unfortunatelly i'm still getting the 28mb response... :(

Comment: @Rothariger, well, it means that your serialized exception size is 28mb. Have you configured serializer somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in [Release 12.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/12.0.1) of Json.NET:

> Change - Excluded TargetSite when serializing Exceptions without SerializableAttribute

The fix was made in commit *[Exclude TargetSite from non-serializable Exception serialization (#1897)](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/commit/998a0aca6371870ac859ab3f0945e2de8e58e69e)* on Oct 27, 2018.

The problem seems to have been introduced in [Json.NET 11.0 Release 1](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2018/02/22/json-net-11-0-release-1-net-standard-2-0-jsonconverters-json-path-and-more):

> Change - Types that implement ISerializable but don't have [SerializableAttribute] are not serialized using ISerializable

For discussion about why the change in 11.0.1 was originally made see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50881884/3744182) to *[Deserializing custom exceptions in Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50845255/3744182)*.