# Can I use TypeConverter attribute on single property of a model for Json serializer?

Tags: c#, json.net, typeconverter

```
public class JsonModel
{
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CidNumberConvertor))]
    [JsonProperty("cid_number")]
    public Cid CidNumber;

    [TypeConverter(typeof(CidHexaConvertor))]
    [JsonProperty("cid_hexa")]
    public Cid CidHexa;

    [JsonProperty("cid_default")]
    public Cid CidDefault;
}
```

Imagine I've 3 fields and all are of type Cid. I've globally registered TypeConvertor `CidHexaConvertor`. It seems `TypeConvertor` attribute is ignored on attributes itself and is invoked only when define on the class/model itself. `CidHexaConvertor` has method to convert string to Cid and Cid to string. I can share more code later, but it seems attributes like this are not possible. Any clue?

Comment: 1) I assume that should be `[JsonProperty("cid_default")]` not `[TypeConverter("cid_default")]`.  2) It would be helpful for testing purposes to have a full [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for `[TypeConverter(typeof(...))]` attributes applied to members is not implemented out of the box in Json.NET.  You could, however, create a [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) that wraps an arbitrary `TypeConverter`, then apply that to your model using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm).

First, define the following `JsonConverter`:

```
public class TypeConverterJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    readonly TypeConverter converter;

    public TypeConverterJsonConverter(Type typeConverterType) : this((TypeConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeConverterType)) { }

    public TypeConverterJsonConverter(TypeConverter converter)
    {
        if (converter == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.converter = converter;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)) && converter.CanConvertTo(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var tokenType = reader.SkipComments().TokenType;
        if (tokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (!tokenType.IsPrimitive())
            throw new JsonSerializationException(string.Format("Token {0} is not primitive.", tokenType));
        var s = (string)JToken.Load(reader);
        return converter.ConvertFrom(null, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, s);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var s = converter.ConvertToInvariantString(value);
        writer.WriteValue(s);
    }
}

public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static JsonReader SkipComments(this JsonReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment && reader.Read())
            ;
        return reader;
    }

    public static bool IsPrimitive(this JsonToken tokenType)
    {
        switch (tokenType)
        {
            case JsonToken.Integer:
            case JsonToken.Float:
            case JsonToken.String:
            case JsonToken.Boolean:
            case JsonToken.Undefined:
            case JsonToken.Null:
            case JsonToken.Date:
            case JsonToken.Bytes:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then apply it to your model as follows:

```
public class JsonModel
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeConverterJsonConverter), typeof(CidNumberConvertor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CidNumberConvertor))]
    [JsonProperty("cid_number")]
    public Cid CidNumber;

    [JsonConverter(typeof(TypeConverterJsonConverter), typeof(CidHexaConvertor))]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(CidHexaConvertor))]
    [JsonProperty("cid_hexa")]
    public Cid CidHexa;

    [JsonProperty("cid_default")]
    public Cid CidDefault;
}
```

Notes:

- Applying a `JsonConverter` overrides use of the global default `TypeConverter` for `Cid`.
- The [`JsonConverterAttribute(Type,Object[])` constructor](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute__ctor_1.htm) is used to pass the specific `TypeConverter` type to the constructor of `TypeConverterJsonConverter` as an argument.
- In production code, I assume those are properties not fields.

Sample fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uSzFD6).   (In the absence of a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I had to create a stub implementation of `Cid`.)

Alternatively, if you have many properties for which you want to use an applied `TypeConverter` when serializing to JSON, you can create a [custom `ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that instantiates and applies `TypeConverterJsonConverter` automatically:

```
public class PropertyTypeConverterContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (property.Converter == null)
        {
            // Can more than one TypeConverterAttribute be applied to a given member?  If so,
            // what should we do?
            var attr = property.AttributeProvider.GetAttributes(typeof(TypeConverterAttribute), false)
                .OfType<TypeConverterAttribute>()
                .SingleOrDefault();
            if (attr != null)
            {
                var typeConverterType = GetTypeFromName(attr.ConverterTypeName, member.DeclaringType.Assembly);
                if (typeConverterType != null)
                {
                    var jsonConverter = new TypeConverterJsonConverter(typeConverterType);
                    if (jsonConverter.CanConvert(property.PropertyType))
                    {
                        property.Converter = jsonConverter;
                        // MemberConverter is obsolete or removed in later versions of Json.NET but
                        // MUST be set identically to Converter in earlier versions.
                        property.MemberConverter = jsonConverter;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return property;
    }

    static Type GetTypeFromName(string typeName, Assembly declaringAssembly)
    {
        // Adapted from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/componentmodel/PropertyDescriptor.cs,1c1ca94869d17fff
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(typeName))
        {
            return null;
        }

        Type typeFromGetType = Type.GetType(typeName);

        Type typeFromComponent = null;
        if (declaringAssembly != null)
        {
            if ((typeFromGetType == null) ||
                (declaringAssembly.FullName.Equals(typeFromGetType.Assembly.FullName)))
            {
                int comma = typeName.IndexOf(',');
                if (comma != -1)
                    typeName = typeName.Substring(0, comma);
                typeFromComponent = declaringAssembly.GetType(typeName);
            }
        }

        return typeFromComponent ?? typeFromGetType;
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
// Cache statically for best performance.
var resolver = new PropertyTypeConverterContractResolver();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = resolver,
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var root2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonModel>(json, settings);
```

Notes:

- You may want to [cache the contract resolver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182) for best performance.
- [`JsonProperty.MemberConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonProperty_MemberConverter.htm) is obsolete in the current version of Json.NET but must be set identically to `JsonProperty.Converter` in earlier versions.

Sample fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/th4l03).

Comment: Thanks for this extensive reply, very appreciate. I had similar solution in mind also. My idea was to basically extend converters(2) to inherit from JsonConverter also, thus implementing ReadJson/WriteJson in a way to call ConvertFrom/ConvertTo internally, but you managed to do it in much more abstract way. Good job!