# How to determine what is causing memory allocation to Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, memory-leaks, json.net

I'm trying to determine where some specific memory utilization is coming from.  I use Json all throughout the code base, when looking at the Managed Memory profiler in Visual Studio 2017, I see Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty is the largest memory consumer.  How do I determine which code is causing the consumption?

[image]

Comment: Largest memory consumer doesn't necessarily mean that it is leaking. How did you determine you have a leak in the first place?

Comment: You're right - it's not necessarily a memory leak, would changing the question to 'how to find unexpected memory consumer' be more appropriate?

Comment: Related: [Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182).