# How can I make ShouldSerialize*() apply only to XML and not JSON serialization?

Tags: c#, json.net, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I'm using the ShouldSerialize method to conditionally serialize a field when I use `XmlSerializer`. But now I need to serialize the same class using JSON, but I would like the ShoulSerialize method to be ignored when using JSON, can I do this in any way?

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    private readonly Customer _customer = new Customer
        {
            FirstName = "Paulo",
            LastName = "Balbino",
            Age = 25
        };

    [Serializable]
    public class Customer
    {
        [XmlElement("FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("LastName")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }

        public bool ShouldSerializeLastName()
        {
            return Age > 30; // Enter here only if it is XmlSerialize.
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void XmlSerialize()
    {
        try
        {
            var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Customer));

            using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
            {
                xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, _customer);
                Debug.WriteLine(textWriter.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void JsonConvert()
    {
        try
        {
            var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_customer);
            Debug.WriteLine(json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Result Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Customer xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <FirstName>Paulo</FirstName>
  <Age>25</Age>
</Customer>
```

Result Json:

```
{"FirstName":"Paulo","Age":25}
```

Both go to the `ShouldSerializeLastName()` method, however, I'd like it to be ignored in JSON and all fields would be displayed.

Comment: JSON serialization (using Newtonsoft.Json, or something else), doesn't use the `ShouldSerialize[Property]` method, it is used by `XmlSerializer`. You can, if you're using Newtonsoft.Json, create a custom converter and do some things to use these methods.

Comment: I edited the code, in the tests I performed both pass through the method.

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 - actually Json.NET does honor the `ShouldSerialize[Property]` as explained in https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm#ShouldSerialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable Json.NET's support for [`ShouldSerialize*()` conditional serialization](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm#ShouldSerialize) by using your own [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#DefaultContractResolver) and setting [`DefaultContractResolver.IgnoreShouldSerializeMembers = true`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_IgnoreShouldSerializeMembers.htm).

First, allocate a contract resolver as follows:

```
static DefaultContractResolver IgnoreShouldSerializeContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
{
    IgnoreShouldSerializeMembers = true,
    //Set other properties as required, e.g.:
    //NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
};
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = IgnoreShouldSerializeContractResolver,
};
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_customer, settings);
```

Notes:

- You may want to [cache the contract](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182) for best performance, as it generates contract information for each type only once, then caches it.
- Because the contract resolver caches type information, modifying properties of a pre-existing contract resolver after it has been constructed and used to generate contracts is not recommended.
- `IgnoreShouldSerializeMembers` was introduced in Json.NET [11.0.1](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/releases/tag/11.0.1).

Sample fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ie0Wja).