# CamelCaseNamingStrategy vs CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver

Tags: json.net

With JSON.Net, I see 2 different ways of saying that I want my properties to be serialized in camelCase:

- [CamelCaseNamingStrategy](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyCamelCase.htm)
- [CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm#CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver)

According to this code snippet, both options give the same result since the assertion does not fail:

```cs
public class Bar
{
    public int SomeValue { get; set; }
}

public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; set; } = new Bar();
    public string AnotherValue { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void TestBothOptions()
{
    var x = new Foo();
    x.AnotherValue = "test";
    x.Bar.SomeValue = 12;

    var serializerSettingsWithNamingStrategy = new JsonSerializerSettings();
    serializerSettingsWithNamingStrategy.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
    };

    var serializerSettingsWithContractResolver = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    };


    var one = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, serializerSettingsWithNamingStrategy);
    var two = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x, serializerSettingsWithContractResolver);

    Assert.Equal(one, two); // {"bar":{"someValue":12},"anotherValue":"test"}
}
```

So, does anybody know the difference between the two options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CamelCaseNamingStrategy` is newer and more flexible to use, since you can specify, via attributes, different naming strategies to use for different classes or properties in your model without using a resolver, e.g.:

```cs
[JsonObject(NamingStrategyType = typeof(CamelCaseNamingStrategy))]
public class MyClass
{
    public string CamelCaseProperty1 { get; set; }

    public string CamelCaseProperty2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(NamingStrategyType = typeof(DefaultNamingStrategy)]
    public string DefaultCaseProperty { get; set; }  
}
```

You can also create your own custom naming strategy class if you need to.

`CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` still survives for backward compatibility.  After `CamelCaseNamingStrategy` was introduced, the source code for that resolver was changed to use the strategy.  You can see this clearly in this excerpt from the [source code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver.cs):

```cs
public class CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    ...

    public CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true,
            OverrideSpecifiedNames = true
        };
    }

    ...
}
```

Note there are subtle differences between the `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` and the `DefaultContractResolver` in terms of how they cache information, which may or may not be of concern to you.  See [Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/10263) for more information about that.