# How to clear cached Contract Resolver in c#

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json` lib for deserializing several `JSON`.
I'm re-using the **default contract resolver** and I'm aware that it caches the types for future uses.

[Here's a print from the memory issue.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHSt0.png)

My problem is that these types will never be the same (I'm always changing the json used), since my program runs indefinitely my memory keeps raising over time.
Is there a way to clear this cached Contract Resolvers from time to time?

**UPDATE 1**

I tried @dbc answer and the memory raise from the **ThreadSafeStore** is not raising anymore:
[dbc answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMhkI.png)
, but the **ConcurrentDictionary's** keeps on raising,is there anything to fix this?
[ConcurrentDictionary's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC7pY.png)

Comment: If you are using `DefaultContractResolver` then if you simply remove all references to your resolver instance, most (not all) memory will be reclaimed.  But if you are using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` all memory is shared globally, so don't do that.  See: [Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182).

Comment: @dbc i just saw the topic you mentioned, but i don't know to apply that on my project, or how to remove all the references from the resolver instance. Can you help me?

Comment: I edited my answer there to simplify it a little.  Basically you remove all references to a resolver (or any .Net object) simply by not retaining any.  This is most easily done by allocating the object within a single method and not returning it out.  An example is shown in the answer.

Comment: @dbc i just tried your first answer and the ThreadSafeStore is not caching memory anymore, but i still keep getting memory raise on the ConcurrentDictionary's, can you help me with that?, i will edit my post with a print

Comment: That's probably something that is cached globally.  As mentioned in the previous answer, some reflection information is cached globally rather than within each resolver.

Comment: Is there a way to clear the global cached information? since my program never stops running i need a way to release that memory.