# Strange accumulation of objects in Gen 2 in asp.net core app

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, memory-management, dependency-injection, out-of-memory

We have an a medium-big asp.net project on dotnet 6. Newtonsoft.JSON and efcore 5 are used.
It's hosted on linux containers governed by k8s on aws.
We're seeing the nodes dying out once in a day or two due to memory issues, they have 4GB RAM available.
When doing memory profiling I've noticed a strange accumulation of instances of `RuntimeTypeHelper`, `GenericFieldInfo`, and `RuntimeMethodHandler` in Generation 2, hundreds of thousands of them after just running locally and navigating thought ~10-20 pages of the application several times over and over. The pages are data-rich, yes, but anyway a steady linear increase in the retained objects count is suspicious.

dotMemory shows they are retained through `ServiceProvider`
[image]
and sampling couple of them, they have some pretty obscure creation stack trace
[image]

I've tried migrating everything to dotnet 7, updating all the libraries and switching to System.Text.Json, that didn't noticeably change the overall picture.

What could be the reason for such objects accumulation? Or conversely, is this normal and I should rather focus on memory pressure and look into decreasing allocations elsewhere?

Comment: Have you looked at articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak  https://www.tessferrandez.com/ Many "leaks" are caused by static collections (like caches of things) that are never (or rarely) cleared/purged.

Comment: @SimonMourier structurally it's indeed this `LIst<Object>` growing over time deep inside `ServiceProvider`. It doesn't look like some issue inside any particular service, but rather something with `ServiceProvider` itself, and I'm struggling to understand why would `ServiceProvider` be doing that exactly, and how to fix that, unfortunately.

Comment: It looks like you are creating run-time types on the fly over and over again using reflection.emit and serializing them with Json.NET.  The problem here is that Json.NET permanently caches metadata about types, see [Does Json.NET cache types' serialization information?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182).  You can reclaim **some** of that by creating and discarding your own `DefaultContractResolver`, but not all -- some info about enums and data contracts is cached globally.

Comment: So your options would appear to be 1) Switch to System.Text.Json which doesn't do that.  2) Cache and reuse the dynamic types rather than creating them over and over again.  In that case the Json.NET memory use will stabilize.

Comment: Incidentally I believe Entity Framework Dynamic Proxies are implemented using Reflection.Emit, see [Proxies using Records with a base class broken since .NET 6 #26602](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/26602).  So you may be able to resolve the problem by disabling dynamic proxies, or mapping the proxies to DTOs before serializing with Json.NET.

Comment: @dbc thanks for the suggestion, will look into the dynamic proxies thing. And will have a closer look at switching to System.Text.Json, maybe I did something wrong then experimenting with switching to it, where I didn't see much difference.

Comment: Hmm, well System.Text.Json might be caching things also, its API is less open than Json.NET.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being caused by our usage of DI.

With the application evolution and rich business rules with a lot of dependencies, lead to the situation where some core services are used by many other services, which in turn may have interdependencies between them. This, combined with the fact that most services were configured as *transient* lead to the situation where one service at the bottom of dependencies graph could have been instantiated hundreds, or in really bad cases even thousands of times for a single tree resolution. That really surprised me, as I don't consider the dependency graph to be *that* bad.

What we did was switch most things to *scoped* lifecycle, so that deep sub-services won't be created multiple times.