# Can I use a appsettings.json record for JsonPropertyName in a class model

Tags: c#, json, .net, json.net, appsettings

I recently came accross this problem. We are using a external API that returns records in a JSON format. But all the keys inside the JSON objects are in a special string.

For example, the JSON would look like this:

```json
{
    "fieldA_0001": "value",
    "fieldA_0002": "value",
    "fieldA_0003": "value" 
}
```

Now in our code the class models are setup like this:

```cs
public class Project {
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName=("fieldA_0001")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName=("fieldA_0002")]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName=("fieldA_0003")]
    public string ProjectCreator { get; set; }
}
```

*Project.cs*

We want to have some keys and values in our appsettings.json that override these hardcoded property names. Like this:

```json
{
    "fieldConfig": {
        "projectNameField": "fieldA_0001",
        "projectDescriptionField": "fieldA_0002",
        "projectCreatorField": "fieldA_0003"
    }
}
```

*appsettings.json*

```cs
public class Project {
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName=(config.GetSection("fieldConfig.projectNameField"))]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName=(config.GetSection("fieldConfig.projectDescriptionField"))]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName=(config.GetSection("fieldConfig.projectCreatorField"))]
    public string ProjectCreator { get; set; }
}
```

*Project.cs*

We want it to be like this whenever the JSON keys are changing because in the event of a project switch all the keys change and result in the external API serving different records.

Is this possible and how would it be possible?

Comment: Pls show the code you have tried  so far and what is the problem, what is not working. You can't just post your fantasy as a question. You should know that property attributes can be only created by a compiler and can not be chanaged duing the runtime

Comment: Arguments you pass to attributes have to have to be constant values as these are locked in at compile time. If you want to base it on a config file, you'll have to look into a different approach.

Comment: You are applying [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute) from System.Text.Json to your model, but you have tagged this Json.NET.  Which JSON serializer are you using?  It's possible to achieve what you want with System.Text.Json in .NET 7 or later, or Json.NET in any version.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to configure property names from injected [`IConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) values at runtime.  If you need this, you will have to implemented it yourself using contract customization in Json.NET (any version) or System.Text.Json (in [.NET 7 and later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization)).  Since you tagged your question [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) but used the attribute [`[JsonPropertyName]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-7.0) from System.Text.Json I'll give answers for both.

Whichever serializer you use, first create a [custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/reflection-and-attributes/creating-custom-attributes) for the configuration key you want to use for a given property:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Property | System.AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class JsonConfiguredPropertyNameAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public string Key { get; }
    public JsonConfiguredPropertyNameAttribute(string key) => this.Key = key;
}
```

Next, apply it to your class as follows:

```
public class Project {
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

    [JsonConfiguredPropertyName("fieldConfig:projectNameField")]
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }

    [JsonConfiguredPropertyName("fieldConfig:projectDescriptionField")]
    public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }

    [JsonConfiguredPropertyName("fieldConfig:projectCreatorField")]
    public string ProjectCreator { get; set; }
}
```

Note that, as explained in [Configuration keys and values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-keys-and-values), hierarchical keys should be referred to using a colon separator `:`:

```
"fieldConfig:projectNameField"
```

**If you use Json.NET**, create the following [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples):

```
public class PropertyNamesFromConfigurationContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly IConfiguration config;
    
    public PropertyNamesFromConfigurationContractResolver(IConfiguration config) => this.config = config ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(config));

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonConfiguredPropertyNameAttribute>()?.Key is {} key)
            property.PropertyName = config[key] ?? property.PropertyName;
        return property;
    }   
}
```

Then, configure your [`JsonSerializerSettings`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm) using some injected `IConfiguration` as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.ContractResolver = new PropertyNamesFromConfigurationContractResolver(config)
{
    // Add other properties as required, e.g.
    NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy(),
};
```

Note that Json.NET's contract resolver [caches contracts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33558665/3744182), so if your configuration changes you will have to construct a new instance of `PropertyNamesFromConfigurationContractResolver`.

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tEz8HK).

**If you use System.Text.Json**, then in .NET 7 and later you can use a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers?view=net-7.0) to customize your type's [contract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/custom-contracts) in a similar manner.

First, create the modifier:

```
public class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> InitializePropertyNamesFromConfiguration(IConfiguration config) => 
        typeInfo => 
        {
            if (typeInfo.Kind == JsonTypeInfoKind.Object)
                foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties)
                    if ((property.AttributeProvider?
                        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(JsonConfiguredPropertyNameAttribute), true)
                        .Cast<JsonConfiguredPropertyNameAttribute>()
                        .SingleOrDefault()?.Key) is {} key)
                        property.Name = config[key] ?? property.Name;
        };
}
```

Then when setting up your [`JsonSerializerOptions`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions?view=net-7.0) apply the modifer as follows, once again making use of some injected `IConfiguration`:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver
{
    Modifiers = { JsonExtensions.InitializePropertyNamesFromConfiguration(config) },
};
// Add other options as required, e.g.
options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
```

Notes:

- There is no way to customize System.Text.Json contracts in .NET versions earlier than .NET 7.
- System.Text.Json is case sensitive (unlike Json.NET) so the field names will have to match exactly unless you set [`JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.propertynamecaseinsensitive?view=net-7.0).
- I believe that `DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver` also caches contracts, so if your configuration changes you may need to replace it with a new instance.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/d29rmD).