# Json.net deserialization with ignore DataMember(Name) attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, json-deserialization

I have a class as follows.

```
[Datacontract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember(Name="p1")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "p2")]
    public string SurName { get; set; }        
}
```

**Case 1**:

json:{"Name":"John","SurName":"Asdf"}

Deserialized object:
customer.Name => null and customer.SurName => null

**Case 2**

Json: {"p1":"John","p2":"Asdf"}

Deserialized object:
customer.Name => John and customer.SurName=>  Asdf

**Problem:**

I have the json in Case1  => {"Name":"John","SurName":"Asdf"}

I wait the deserialized object in Case2 =>
customer.Name => John and customer.SurName=>  Asdf

So, How I can provide during deserialization that ignore DataMember(Name) attribute?

**Solved:**

```
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        property.PropertyName = member.Name;

        return property;
    }
```

Thank you @dbc

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Configure JSON.NET to ignore DataContract/DataMember attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055225/3744182).  Does that answer your question sufficiently?

Comment: it is not exactly. I try to ignore DataMember attribute's Name field. [DataMember(Name="p1")]  In here, Name="p1" is make deserialization wrong.

Comment: So you want to respect the `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` attributes *except that you want to ignore the `DataMember.Name` value*?  (Oh, by the way, your `Customer` type must also be marked with `[DataContract]`; can you confirm?)

Comment: Yes. Because I dont have a chance to change Customer Class. Therefore I can not add JsonObject attribute  to CustomerClass Properties.

Comment: Yes, Customer class marked with [Datacontract]

Comment: And ignoring data contract attributes completely, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11055225/3744182) isn't good enough?  That should be sufficient for example class `Customer`.  Do you have an example where this is not good enough?

Comment: yes, it is solved. it is my fault.  thank you @dbc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Configure JSON.NET to ignore DataContract/DataMember attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055225/configure-json-net-to-ignore-datacontract-datamember-attributes)

Comment: Rather than adding the solution to the problem into the question itself, could you please [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) or [mark it as a duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79916/is-it-possible-to-mark-my-own-question-as-duplicate-of-another) so others can tell at a glance that it has been answered?

Answer (score 1):

Can you deserialize it with below ? :

```
var customerModelData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(jsonCustomerData);
```

Comment: Yes. But although  Name or Surname property in json have a value, deserialized object's values is Null. Because properties have datamember attribute with Name field. Json deserializer wait p1 or p2 property. But my Json have Name and Surname property.

Answer (score 0):

Define class property this way :

```
[JsonProperty(Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.AllowNull)]
public string Name  { get; set;}
```

Comment: I don't have a chance to change my class