# WCF calling service method with an Interface argument results in SocketException

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a **WCF** Service where I have implemented a service method with an out argument of a type which is an Interface like this

```
bool GetFoo(out IFoo foo)
{
    foo = new AFoo();
    return true;
}
```

Here **IFoo** is the interface & **AFoo** is the concrete type that inherits.

Then on the Client Side I am calling this method using the service reference & receving the following error

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while
>   receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://localhost:4504/MyService. This could be due to the
>   service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also
>   be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server
>   (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more
>   details.'

What is Interesting is that when I remove the interface argument from the service method, everything works just fine. For example

```
bool GetFoo()
{
    IFoo foo = new AFoo();
    return true;
}
```

The **AFoo** type is already a known type on the Client side and I can use it normally.

---

**Update 1**

Adding a **Base Class Foo** such that Afoo inherits from Foo & Foo inherits from IFoo
ex: AFoo : Foo : IFoo (logically) has the **same error** when the service method is modified as

```
bool GetFoo(out Foo foo)
{
    foo = new AFoo();
    return true;
}
```

Again I kept all Classes & Interfaces empty (meaning they have nothing inside them)

---

Update 2

The following seems to work perfectly fine

```
bool GetFoo(out AFoo foo)
{
    foo = new AFoo();
    return true;
}
```

Why did not the Base Class Foo worked? Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you try removing the `out` ? Is AFoo class decorated with DataContract attribute?

Comment: out is not a problem. why, because all my service methods have out arguments and it works fine. Also as I said AFoo is already a known type.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this other question: [DataContract and inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555089/datacontract-and-inheritance)

It seems like you need to decorate the base class with `KnownType` of the sub-class to do this kind of thing, and have them both under `DataContract` of course.

Comment: Thanks @Kevin , this is what has worked for me so far, It is not a proper solution since this requires me to have a Base Class for the inheritance though I wanted to use the Interface implementations. I am gonna add an answer on how I made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this because the type contained a reference to an `enum` type that was not marked with the `DataContract` attribute. The error you're seeing is most likely hiding an inner error like that. Sometimes you can catch these by going to Debug -> Exceptions and turning on 'break on all thrown exceptions'.

Comment: I even tried removing all the Properties from the Class AFoo & the interface IFoo , same result

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround**:

> Note: this is not an answer, since it forces to create a Base Class.

I got it working finally and I am gonna share what I did. In short, I was missing the **KnownType** in the **DataContract**.

Firstly, I had to Add a Base Class **Foo** as described in the question section. Next I had
to Add the **KnownType** attributes with all the Child(inherited) classes, in my case it was only **AFoo**.

Here is what the code looks like

```
public interface IFoo
{
}

[DataContract]
[KnownType(typeof(AFoo))]
public class Foo : IFoo
{ // this is the Base Class
}

public class AFoo : Foo
{
}
```

Now the service method looks like this

```
bool GetFoo(out Foo foo)
{
    foo = new AFoo();
    return true;
}
```

### All Good!!

It would be nice if instead it was possible to have the service method like thie following (without needing a Base Class)

```
bool GetFoo(out IFoo foo)
{
    foo = new AFoo();
    return true;
}
```